# how to display the upc in product page with opencart3?

Tags: php, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I want to display the upc in product page with opencart 3. How do I do that?

I added the below code into my template file `/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.twig`，but it doesn't work.

```
{% if upc %}
    {{ upc }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please do not forget to backup these files first.**

You have to add upc as a variable to the controller first and then echo it in the template.
in order to do that:
first edit controller file:

```
/catalog/controller/product/product.php
```

and search for

```
$data['model'] = $product_info['model'];
```

after that add:

```
$data['upc'] = $product_info['upc'];
```

and save the file.

After that your code in template file that you mentioned will work.

**ps: by this approach you lose these changes if you update opencart.A better approach would be to make an ocmod extension for it.**